# CSS hover effects only work with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make some text appear over an image when the image is hovered over.

This is typically a simple process, however apparently :hover doesn't work if the first div (for example)

`first.div:hover second.div {`

over (in my case an image) is using relative positioning instead of absolute.

There are lots of images in this page and they are set up as tables through CSS with attributes such as display:table; so I don't think I have the option of switching to absolute positioning. I know CSS tables aren't generally condoned, but I absolutely have to do it this way.

Right now I'm using opacity changes to try to make the text appear. I've tried using z-index too, but I think the problem is that the :hover effect doesn't work well with absolute positioning. What workarounds, if any, are available?

I'm not opposed to using languages other than HTML/CSS, but I'm pretty inexperienced and I don't understand them, so I'd prefer a CSS work around for this, but beggars aren't choosers.

As requested, here's some code:

HTML

`<div class="cell"><img class="box" src="image1.jpg"><div id="text">Text text text</div></div>`

CSS

`.cell {
        position:relative;
        display:table-cell;
        background-color:black;
        width:700px;
        height:auto;
        }`
`#text {
        display:table;
        position:absolute;
        z-index:999;
        color:#fff;
        text-align:center;
        width:100%;
        top:48%;
        left:0;
        }`

`img {
        max-height:600px;
        max-width:600px;
        height:auto;
        width:100%;
        filter: url(filters.svg#grayscale); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
        filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Google Chrome, Safari 6+ & Opera 15+ */
        opacity:0.4;
        z-index:2;
        }`

`img:hover {
        filter: none;
        -webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
        opacity:1.0;
        }`

I'm not sure on what's causing this so I included a lot more than necessary... I'm a little new to coding so take it easy on me, but I can't get `cell.div:hover #text  { opacity:1;}` to work. I read somewhere that this is because hover effects don't work with relatively positioned divs...

Comment: Mind showing some code?

Comment: Z-index only works within the same style of positioning - so absolutely positioned elements only take account of each other's z-index and ignore relativley position elements, and vice versa.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin: could you provide some source reference for that claim? or maybe a fiddle to demonstrate that?

Comment: I am not reading all this...create a fiddle....jsfiddle.net

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin not sure that's true, http://jsfiddle.net/57gZG/. In regards to the question, show us the code you have so far, we can't help you unless we know what you're doing.

Comment: @MLeFevre I may well be wrong. Allow me to rephrase: I've always had trouble getting z-index to work when elements were positioned differently, and that also appears to be happening to the OP. In all likelihood, I'm making a similar mistake to them.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin what you said about positioning is not factual.  Read the z-index specification before making claims like that.  An element (and its parents) has to have an explicitly defined position (e.g. not `static`), but past that it is based on stacking context in that level of the DOM.

Comment: @BFDatabaseAdmin also if BF stands for Battlefield high five! I founded and used to run one of the large BF fansites.

Comment: @Ennui - Yes, my bad. However, I'll leave my erroneous comment there so that all the follow up comments make sense!

Comment: Hey I threw some code in there. Was avoiding doing it because there's a lot of it, and I'm not sure what exactly is causing it, so my apologies on all the extra stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, literally 30 seconds after I took the time to post all of my code I found a solution. I used `div.cell:hover #text {
opacity:1; }`
and everything worked. Not sure what I was doing wrong it was a late night and probably tried to do something dumb like `img.box:hover #text` commands. Anyway disregard this question guys, and thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not getting you proper, what is your issue. And if you are clear to you have problem in only opacity, then you can use css as below.

```
first.div:hover second.div {
cursor: pointer;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=75)";
filter: alpha(opacity=75);
-khtml-opacity: 0.75;
-moz-opacity: 0.75;
opacity: 0.75; }
```

If it's not work for you, then please share your code or live link, then explain you proper.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use `opacity` to achieve this. Make sure you are targeting the pic on hover. Check out this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Davidicus/69ZTN/